# AddEventListener Issue, For-Loop Issue?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, openweathermap

I'm trying to use a for-loop to iterate through data from open weather map API that returns data from a 5-day forecast.

Currently I am building a weather app that provides not only current city data provided by user input, but also the weekly data of that same city. As of now on my current weather data is fetched and displaying from the API correctly. I chose to use a `for` Loop to get the minimum and maximum temperatures as well as the weather icons for each day of the week. No problems are displaying within my code itself as of now.

However, initially when I was running the `fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo` function in my browser console it was returning an error that read:

> uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cannot set properties of null (setting 'inner text')

a user thoughtfully suggested to me that the issue might be fixed by putting my for-loops and everything within the `fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo` function into a `load` event listener. That doing this might then make my `innerText` available. However, when I did this (as reflected in my code currently) and then tried to run `fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo` the only thing I started getting back is

> ReferenceError: fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo is not defined.

Admittedly, I am not familiar or comfortable enough with for-loops as of yet to understand where the breakdown is occurring. It may not even be with the for Loop itself. Because of this I am including my HTML just in case the issue isn't even within my JavaScript. I appreciate all help as I am self-taught and this is the final piece hanging me up on this project.

HTML:

```
    <div class="card">
        <div id="Search">
        <input type=" text" placeholder = "City" id="Search-Bubble"/>
        <button id="SearchBtn">Search</button>
      </div>
        <div class="current-Info">
           
            <div class="location-weather">
                <h2 id="City">Weather in Seattle</h2>
                <h1 id="Temperature">75° F</h1>
                <img src= "" class="weather-icon" id="Weather-Icon" alt="weather icon">
                <div class="descripton" id="CityWeatherDescription">Clear</div>
            </div>

            <div class="current-weather-stats" id="Current-Weather-Stats">
                    <div class="humidity-weather-stat">
                        <p>Humidity</p>
                        <p>75%</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wind-speed-weather-stat">
                        <p>Wind Speed</p>
                        <p>2m/hr</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feels-like-weather-stat">
                        <p></p>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>   


<div class="upcoming-forecast">
    <div class="today" id="Today">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="day-of-the-week">Monday</div>
            <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
            <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
        

   
 <div class="weather-forecast" id="Weather-Forecast">
        <div class="daily-forecast-info">
            <div class="day-of-the-week">Tuesday</div>
             <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon"> 
            <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
            <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="weather-forecast" id="Weather-Forecast">
            <div class="daily-forecast-info">
                <div class="day-of-the-week">Wednesday</div>
                 <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon"> 
                <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
                <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
            </div>
            <div class="weather-forecast" id="Weather-Forecast">
                <div class="daily-forecast-info">
                    <div class="day-of-the-week">Thursday</div>
                     <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon"> 
                    <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
                    <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
                </div>
                <div class="weather-forecast" id="Weather-Forecast">
                    <div class="daily-forecast-info">
                        <div class="day-of-the-week">Friday</div>
                         <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon"> 
                        <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
                        <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weather-forecast" id="Weather-Forecast">
                        <div class="daily-forecast-info">
                            <div class="day-of-the-week">Saturday</div>
                             <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon"> 
                            <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
                            <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="weather-forecast" id="Weather-Forecast">
                            <div class="daily-forecast-info">
                                <div class="day-of-the-week">Sunday</div>
                                 <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="weather icon" class="weather-icon"> 
                                <div class="temp-high">High : 85°</div>
                                <div class="temp-low">Low : 68°</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fetchCurrentWeatherInfo(city) {
  const currentWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${currentWeatherApiTag}`;
  fetch(currentWeatherUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => unveilCurrentWeather(data));
};

function unveilCurrentWeather(data) {
  const {name} = data;
  const {icon} = data.weather[0];
  const {description} = data.weather[0];
  const {temp} = data.main;
  const {humidity} = (data.main);
  const {speed} = data.wind;

  console.log(name, icon, description, temp, humidity, speed);
  document.querySelector("#City").innerText = "Weather in " + name;
  document.querySelector("#Weather-Icon").src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;
  document.querySelector("#CityWeatherDescription").innerText = description;
  document.querySelector("#Temperature").innerText = temp + " °F";
  document.querySelector(".humidity-weather-stat").innerText = "Humidity : " + humidity + "%";
  document.querySelector(".wind-speed-weather-stat").innerText = "Wind Speed : " + speed + "m/hr";
};

window.addEventListener("load", fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo(city)) {
  const weekWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${weekForecastApiTag}`;
  fetch(weekWeatherUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector(".day-of-the-week" + (i + 1) + ".temp-high").innerText = "High :" + Number(data.list[0].main.temp_max - 74.57).toFixed(2) + "°F";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector(".day-of-the-week" + (i + 1) + ".temp-low").innerText = "Low :" + Number(data.list[0].main.temp_min - 74.57).toFixed(2) + "°F";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector("#Weather-Icon" + (i + 1)).src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.list[0].weather[0].icon}.png`;
      }
    })
}

function searchCurrentWeather() {
  fetchCurrentWeatherInfo(document.querySelector("#Search-Bubble").value);
};

document.getElementById("SearchBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  searchCurrentWeather();
});

document.getElementById("Search-Bubble").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    searchCurrentWeather();
  }
});
```

Please note: I have omitted a few pieces of my HTML including the head portion and date/time, they do exist but everything is linked correctly. Thus, it didn't seem necessary to include

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo` function. You put what should be the function body after the `addEventListener()` call, not inside a function definition.

The second argument to `addEventListener()` has to be a function reference, not a call to the function. You can use an anonymous function for this. It needs a city argument to pass to the function, I picked London arbitrarily. It's not clear what you really want this to do when the page is first loaded, since the user hasn't selected a city yet.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo('london'); })

function fetchWeeklyWeatherInfo(city)) {
  const weekWeatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${weekForecastApiTag}`;
  fetch(weekWeatherUrl)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector(".day-of-the-week" + (i + 1) + ".temp-high").innerText = "High :" + Number(data.list[0].main.temp_max - 74.57).toFixed(2) + "°F";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector(".day-of-the-week" + (i + 1) + ".temp-low").innerText = "Low :" + Number(data.list[0].main.temp_min - 74.57).toFixed(2) + "°F";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        document.querySelector("#Weather-Icon" + (i + 1)).src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.list[0].weather[0].icon}.png`;
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but for some reason this solution is still not working even doing it exactly the way you have it written. It just went right back to the original error of: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cannot set properties of null (setting 'inner text') I have no idea what's causing this error.

Comment: You don't have classes like `day-of-the-week1` in the HTML, it's just `class="day-of-the-week"`.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But then if I break it up like that day-of-the-week-1, etc. How would I then get the minimum and maximum temps for example to go to each day. It can't be to write a loop for each one. That's inefficient. I apologize. As I'm sure it's obvious but as I've said I knew. Do you care to explain? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I would use `document.querySelectorAll(".day-of-the-week")` and loop over this, setting the nested elements of each to the appropriate values from the objects.